How does a sphere stop rolling if friction favours rotation?
I have just studied rotation and am confused about how a sphere rolling on a rough horizontal surface stops. As the friction force would try to decrease linear momentum its direction will cause  increase in angular momentum then how will the sphere stop both rotating and translating. If we assume pure rolling we may be able to explain it with $v=rw$ but I don't think that pure rolling is possible in such a case as $v$ is increasing and $w$ decreasing. Also if we do consider pure rolling what force would be doing the work to stop the sphere from rolling.

I assume that by pure rolling you mean rolling without friction. In this case, assuming no other forces act on the sphere, it will keep rolling indefinitely

In the real world, rolling resistance is due to inelastic and/or visicoelastic behavior of the rolling object and/or the surface upon which it rolls.

If the sphere is initially sliding horizontally along a hypothetical perfectly frictionless surface without rotating, it will start rotating when it arrives a rough part of the surface, This is indeed due to the torque caused by the sliding friction due the contact point of the sphere moving relative to the horizontal surface. As the sphere spins up, it reaches a point where the rearward motion of the lowest part of the sphere is stationary relative to the 'road' surface. This means the sliding friction vanishes and there is longer any torque being applied to the sphere as long as nothing is trying to accelerate or decelerate the the sphere. As the sphere 'spins up' to acquire the correct rotation rate for pure rolling motion it gains angular velocity and this comes at the expense of the losing some of its linear velocity.
In practice there will always be some residual energy loss due to various factors. Even a hard billiard ball rolling on a hard surface make a sound and that represents an energy loss. The weight of the sphere tends to indent the surface and the energy require to temporarily compress the surface represents another energy loss. The region of the rolling surface (and the region of the sphere (or wheel) that is actively being compressed during rolling is slightly ahead of the contact point and results in a reverse torque that that tend to slow down the rolling motion. There is also friction due to moving through the air which directly slows down the horizontal motion of the sphere.
If all the energy losses could be completed eliminated the sphere would continue to rule forward with constant velocity indefinitely due to conservation of linear and angular momentum. This is difficult to achieve in practice.


As the friction force would try to decrease linear momentum its direction will cause increase in angular momentum then how will the sphere stop both rotating and translating ?

It won't.
Friction between two surfaces acts to oppose any relative motion between the surfaces. This may reduce linear momentum but it does not have to. For example, consider a box on the floor of an accelerating van. Friction between the floor of the van and the box will keep the box moving at the same speed as the van (if it is strong enough) but, since the van is accelerating, in this case friction actually increases the linear momentum of the box.
In the case of a sphere rolling on a rough horizontal surface, friction opposes any sliding motion between the sphere and the ground, but if the sphere's angular speed $\omega$ and its linear speed $v$ are related by $v = -r\omega$ then the point where the sphere touches the ground is stationary with respect to the ground and friction ceases to act. If $v = -r\omega$ then in principle the sphere can continue rolling for ever - in practice, air resistance and small irregularities in the surface will eventually slow it down.
So if you start out pushing a sphere, so that $v > 0$ and $\omega=0$, then friction will decrease $v$ and increase $|\omega|$ until $v = -r\omega$, after which the sphere will (in theory) continue rolling for ever.
There is a nice demonstration of this effect with a table tennis ball. If you put your finger near the top of the ball and push down quickly on the side facing you, so that $v > 0$ and $\omega$ is large and positive then by the time the ball reaches $v = -r\omega$ its speed $v$ has become negative. So the table tennis ball will initially slide away from you, and then stop and roll back towards you.
